# Is it possible to do a dynamic LLVM assembler (from a higher level language like Java)?

Tags: java, scala, assembly, dynamic, llvm

In [this example](https://github.com/guillaumebort/scasm/blob/master/scasm.scala) - the author

1. takes input in a higher level language (eg Scala),
2. takes a String,
3. skips over the JVM via the `sun.misc.Unsafe` library,
4. allocates memory dynamically,
5. creates a function dynamically, and
6. executes the function.

all effectively on the REPL. (As per the live coding presentation at Devoxx FR16).

Now I don't know enough about the LLVM toolchain. I understand that for both the JVM and LLVM you can compile some code and run it. The JVM also has dynamic facilities via Classloaders, `invokedynamic` and reflection.

My question is: **Is it possible to do a dynamic LLVM assembler (from a higher level language like Java)?**

Comment: As I understand it, LLVM has a library interface that can take an ASCII string of [LLVM intermediate representation, aka LLVM assembly language](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html), and write native machine code for a function into a buffer.  *If* you can call that LLVM API function from your language of choice, and treat the buffer pointer as a function pointer, then you should be all set.  If not, then you can't.

Comment: Cool - do you know of a project that uses that?

Comment: The LLVM API in general, or from a "managed" language?  Either way, the answer is no.  :P  I just know it exists, and I think I've seen a C example of using it once.

Answer (score 0):

There are folks doing projects like that - [Scala Native](https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native) and [Scala Offheap](https://github.com/densh/scala-offheap)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful - could you please link to a place that says they run on LLVM?

Comment: Scala Native uses LLVM, but it is a *static* ahead-of-time compiler. Scala Offheap uses `sun.misc.Unsafe`, not LLVM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use LLVM MC JIT along with ExecutionEngine to runtime compile and execute code.

Comment: Cool - do you know of any projects using that?